# Zend Form Error messages are not returning from functions

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

In my model

```
$form = new \Zend_Form();
$form->addElement('text', 'name', array(
        'validators'    => array(
            array('NotEmpty', true),
            array("stringLength", true, array(1,40))
        ),
        'required'      => true,
        'label'         => "Name",
    ));
return $form;
```

In my controller,  called above model function

```
if($form->isValid($_POST)) {
  ....
} else {
$form = Product::getForm();
print_r($form->getErrors());
print_r($form->getErrorMessages());
print_r($form->getMessages());
}
```

I am using Zend Framework.

Here in name field in form, string with more than 40 chars needs to display error messages.

I tried with get error with `getErrors()` and `getErrorMessages()`. But none of these function give me error.
It returns an empty array on printing the these functions.

Please help me to solve this problem...

Comment: No problem, just worth mentioning when it's low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why make you this call:

```
$form = Product::getForm();
```

So you overwrite the old $form variable with its error messages. Try it without these line.

Comment: Code provided for model in question is `function getForm()`

Comment: @Justin: Thargor is right. Your controller sequence starts with a `$form` instance, but after you call `$form = Product::getForm()`, you are blasting the old form and creating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

The error messages will not be there until you call `isValid()` on the form, like so

```
$form = Product::getForm();

if(!$form->isValid($_POST))
{
    print_r($form->getErrors());
    print_r($form->getErrorMessages());
    print_r($form->getMessages());        
}
```

Comment: Already the code is in that format... I have edited the question.

Comment: Ah, well the original question wasn't in that format. Does your `Product::getForm()` override `isValid()`?  Or any of the other functions? If you leave the field empty, does it fire the `NotEmpty` error?

Comment: Code provided for model is `function getForm()`. I don't think it  will override the `$form`.